# Is there a way to place the open/close button of a navigation menu outside the nav element without hurting accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility, user-experience, semantic-markup

I couldn't find a clear answer/explanation to this question so far.

This seems uncontroversial from an accessibility perspective:

Example A:

```
<header>

  <!-- Other stuff like a logo or other buttons -->

  <nav>
    <button>Menu</button>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

However from a UI design perspective, this may be limiting. It would be liberating to have a markup like this:

Example B:

```
<header>

  <!-- Other stuff like a logo or other buttons -->

  <button>Menu</button>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

In either case, if the navigation was closed, the `nav` element would not have to be hidden, it would be enough to hide the `ul` element using display none.

Although in example B, hiding the `nav` element (i.e. the entire navigation) might be better from a UX perspective, since a closed navigation without an open/close button as a child might be confusing, but I am not sure.

Comment: In what way would placing the button in the nav be limiting from a UI-design perspective? With CSS, you can style it to appear as though it is outside.

Comment: @Sean Imagine the header is a grid container with other stuff like like a logo and other buttons.In such a case, in example B, we can place the logo, open/close button, nav etc. wherever we want on the grid, since all of them would be grid items. In example A, we don't have this flexibility.

Comment: I don't see well why example B would be a problem for accessibility. However, you must clearly hide the full nav element when the menu is closed.

Comment: @QuentinC Why should we hide the full nav? Because of the accessibility concern I have mentioned? I don't know if B is a problem or not, hence my question. The reason I think A might be better is because the relationship between the button and the nav is clear. Here is an article touching on this: https://www.a11ymatters.com/pattern/mobile-nav/ "Notice that it didn’t announce the button is related to the <nav> element. This is confusing and not good for the user."

Comment: I think B isn't a problem, but that's maybe because I'm using Jaws since more than 15 years and generally don't care at all about landmarks. I find that headings are much more crucial for efficient navigation.
That's only my opinion. At the end, probably that both A and B ave pros and cons and can both be correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

Option 1 is better as the semantics make relationships obvious. Option 2 can be made just as accessible with `aria` attributes (assuming they are supported by the users screen reader and browser combo).

Choose option 1 unless there is absolutely no way to achieve your desired design with positioning etc. (which I would argue is very rare!)

### Longer Answer

80%+ of accessibility is semantics and semantic relationships.

In your first example the button to control the menu is part of the navigation, which makes perfect sense. This has the added benefit of making any focus trapping and management if this is a modal type menu (you didn't specify but the pattern suggests it might be) a lot easier.

In your second example, having an empty `<nav>` element as you have hidden the `<ul>` is *not ideal* as navigating by landmarks could still lead some screen readers to show that landmark, so when a user navigates to it they would find it is empty.

The other option is to hide the `<nav>` element entirely which is also not ideal as when navigating by landmarks there would be no `<nav>`.

If you want to use the second mark-up despite these drawbacks WAI-ARIA can help with defining the relationship between the button and the menu etc.

By using [`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-haspopup) and [`aria-owns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-owns) on the `<button>` (don't forget `aria-expanded` but that one is needed for both examples).

**Please note:** [`aria-controls`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-controls) is actually the more appropriate aria attribute instead of `aria-owns`, but [support is not great for `aria-controls` sadly](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-controls_attribute).

### Final thoughts

Yet again you did not specify if this is a modal type menu, but I am assuming it is from the pattern.

As such [you need to consider focus trapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083587/2702894) and making it clear that the menu button acts as both an open and a close button depending on the menu state. For that you could use some [visually hidden text](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) within the button to indicate the state, which is better than relying on `aria-expanded` alone:

```
<!--closed state-->
<button aria-expanded="false"><span class="visually-hidden">Open </span>Menu</button>
<!--opened state-->
<button aria-expanded="true"><span class="visually-hidden">Close </span>Menu</button>
```